# Ajax GET content from php page

Tags: html, mysql, ajax, get

Hi I have a table which I am trying to update with a call to a MySQL database in a separate php page. This separate page loops through a result set and builds the table through a series of echos. In the main page I am trying to insert that echoed content into a div.

This is all kicked off by the user selecting an option from a drop down box.

This is the separate php page. (It works fine when i manually type in the GET parameters, it is the link between the two pages which doesn't seem to work)

tableGetter.php

```
<?PHP
$user_name = "rocketeermus_pr";
$password = "zuluhead2";
$database = "rocketeermus_pr";
$server = "pdb1.awardspace.com";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

echo "Bonjour";

if (isset($_GET['composer'])){ 

  echo "Helloooo";

  if ($db_found) {

    echo "SELECT * FROM catalogue WHERE Composer = '".mysql_escape_string($_GET['composer'])."';";
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM catalogue WHERE Composer = '".mysql_escape_string($_GET['composer'])."';";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_GB");

    echo "<table class=\"sortable\" id=\"moder\" width=\"800\">";

    echo "<th>TITLE</th><th>COMPOSER</th><th>VOICING</th><th>PRICE</th><th></th></tr>";
    while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
      echo "Hi.";

      echo "<tr><td>{$db_field['Title']}</td><td>{$db_field['Composer']}</td><td>{$db_field['Voicing']}</td><td>";
      echo money_format("%n", $db_field['Price']);
      echo "</td><td> <div class=\"product\"> <input value=\"{$db_field['Title']}\" class=\"product-title\" type=\"hidden\"> <input value=\"0.5\" class=\"product-weight\" type=\"hidden\"> <input value=\"{$db_field['NoVox']}\" class=\"googlecart-quantity\" type=\"hidden\"> <input value=\"{$db_field['Price']}\" class=\"product-price\" type=\"hidden\"> <div title=\"Add to cart\" role=\"button\" tabindex=\"0\" class=\"googlecart-add-button\"> </div> </div> </td></tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysql_close($db_handle);

  } else {
    print "Database NOT Found ";
    mysql_close($db_handle);
  }
}

?>
```

And here is the important stuff from the main page:

Javascript:

```
function getdata()
{
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    if (req)
    {

        //function to be called when state is changed
        var queryString1 = "";
        req.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            //when state is completed i.e 4
            if (req.readyState == 4)
            {

                var ajaxSearchResults1 = document.getElementById("table");
                ajaxSearchResults1.innerHTML = req.responseText;

                // only if http status is "OK"
                if (req.status == 200)
                {
                    var new1 = document.getElementById('composer').value;
                    queryString1 = "?composer=" + encodeURIComponent(new1);
                    console.log (queryString1);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }
        }
        req.open("GET", "tableGetter.php" + queryString1, true);
        req.send();
    }
}

function getXMLHTTP() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){ //For Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, and Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){ //For ie
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (!xmlhttp){
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="menus">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><form action=""">
            <select name="composer" id ="composer" onchange="getdata();"> 
              <?php  
                 $user_name = "***";
                 $password = "****";
                 $database = "****";
                 $server = "****.com";

                 $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
                 $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

                 if ($db_found) {

                 $SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Composer FROM catalogue ORDER BY Composer";
                 $result = mysql_query($SQL);
                 setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_GB");
                 while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) { 
                 ?> 
              <option id="composer" onchange="getdata();" value="<?php echo $db_field['Composer'];?>"> 
                <?php  
                   echo $db_field['Composer']; 
                   ?> 
              </option> 
              <?php 
                 } 
                 }
                 ?> 
            </select>


      </form></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="table"> 
  <?php include("tableGetter.php"); ?>
</div>
```

The html on the main page works fine, the drop down menu fills up nicely with all the distinct composer names in the database. When an option in the menu is selected the only thing echoed in the "table" div is "Bonjour". It's not getting further than `if (isset($_GET['composer']))` in the `tableGetter.php` page. I'm printing out the `queryString1` variable (The get parameters) which is requested in the `getData()` function and it reports: `?composer=Animuccia%2C%20Paulo` which works perfectly when loading the page manually. It just won't work dynamically!

Anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: You're setting `queryString1` in the callback function, not when you send the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting `queryString1` before sending the AJAX request. Try this rewrite of `getdata()`.

```
function getdata()
{
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    if (req)
    {
        //function to be called when state is changed
        req.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            //when state is completed i.e 4
            if (req.readyState == 4)
            {
                // only if http status is "OK"
                if (req.status == 200)
                {
                    var ajaxSearchResults1 = document.getElementById("table");
                    ajaxSearchResults1.innerHTML = req.responseText;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }
        }
        var new1 = document.getElementById('composer').value;
        var queryString1 = "?composer=" + encodeURIComponent(new1);
        req.open("GET", "tableGetter.php" + queryString1, true);
        req.send();
    }
}
```